# xamarin device owner self upgrade only updates manifest, not executables

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, upgrade

I have a strange problem. I have a kiosk application (running as device owner, set by dpm) that is attempting to perform a self upgrade from an apk file that has already been downloaded. The file is downloaded correctly and the upgrade appears to work correctly. The application quits, the system gives a notification that the application has been upgraded by the device owner before the application relaunches.

When the application has relaunched, the version number is reporting as the new version, but none of the modified functionality in the app is present. On the initial login form I added a label with the version number hardcoded into it to compare to the version pulled using Xamarin.Essentials.AppInfo.Version.ToString(). The hardcoded version does not update, but the software version shows correctly.

The device is a Samsung Galaxy Tab A.

I have added a toast on exception which is showing no error messages. I have tried changing the PackageInstallMode to InheritExisting, this didn't seem to make any difference.

The method used for the upgrade is here.

```
    public void UpgradeFromLocalFile(string downloadedFile)
    {
        try
        {

            if (MainActivity.Instance.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) == Permission.Denied)
            {
                MainActivity.Instance.RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, 0);
            }
            if (MainActivity.Instance.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) == Permission.Denied)
            {
                MainActivity.Instance.RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage }, 0);
            }
            if (MainActivity.Instance.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.InstallPackages) == Permission.Denied)
            {
                MainActivity.Instance.RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.InstallPackages }, 0);
            }


            var installer = MainActivity.Instance.PackageManager.PackageInstaller;
            var parameters = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstallMode.FullInstall);
            parameters.SetAppPackageName("my.package.name");
            var sessionid = installer.CreateSession(parameters);
            var session = installer.OpenSession(sessionid);
            var fis = File.OpenRead(downloadedFile);
            using (var outputstream = session.OpenWrite("my.package.name", 0, -1))
            {
                fis.CopyTo(outputstream);
                session.Fsync(outputstream);
                outputstream.Close();
                outputstream.Dispose();
                fis.Close();
                fis.Dispose();
                GC.Collect();
            }

            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(MainActivity.Instance, sessionid, new Intent(Intent.ActionInstallPackage), 0);
            session.Commit(pendingIntent.IntentSender);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(MainActivity.Instance.ApplicationContext, string.Format("Update failed, you may not have full device admin privileges. Error - {0}", ex.ToString()), ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
```

I'd expect the software version to change as well as the actual executable version. Does anyone have any clues as to what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after much stuffing around and inspecting install logs with logcat, it seems the apk I was generating by deploy is incomplete. I had to set up a keystore to sign my app and then create a complete archive.

Right click the android proj -> archive.. -> Distribute -> Ad Hoc

This allowed me to self update properly.

Phew. Was bashing my head against it for days. Hope this saves someone else some time.